# Basic platform game Rectangle based collision problems

Tags: c#, xna

**Background:** I've been doing a lot of studying in xna lately. I've been perfecting my game structure and creating essential classes for an average game, read a couple articles, watched a number of videos, and read bits of a book I have. So, after creating a good game structure I moved on to the actual game, a platformer. I currently have ordinary blocks, and a Player - and the problem is within the player.

**Problem/Question:** Colliding with blocks is usually fine, but sometimes collisions act strangely. IE: Some how the player is in the block ( normally one pixel in ), and this is a big problem because this could cause the player to be pushed some where across the map.

**Player Game Logic:** The player's movement is state based. The states are an enumerator of "ground, jump, and fall". Right now, the problem seems to be inside of the falling state. Sometimes the collision works correct, sometimes the player ends up one pixel inside of the block - which means if the player jumps he will be instantly pushed to the first block above the player - no matter how far.

**Collision Logic:** Inside the fall state the player is pushed towards the floor by gravity. Gravity gets added by the force every frame. Before changing the position, a collision method is called upon checking if there was a collision between any block within it's range of motion. Now, since this is a falling state the player is moving down, so when it collides a while loop pushes the player down by 1pixel every frame until it's meeting the block. And just as a back up, there's a loop that pushes the player out of the block. Then it sets the current state to ground. The jumping state follows the same kind of theory.

**Falling State Script:** Read above for explanation of this code.

```
case PlayerState.Fall:
    // falling sprite
        mySpriteManager.mySpriteCurrent = mySpriteManager.mySpriteIndex["PlayerSprites/player_fall"];
    // fall velocity change
        myVelocity.Y += myDforce;

    if ( Collision( otObjectList.wallIndex, myPosition.X + 1, myPosition.Y, myPosition.X + myWidth - 1, myPosition.Y + myHeight + myVelocity.Y) )
    {
        while( !Collision( otObjectList.wallIndex, myPosition.X + 1, myPosition.Y, myPosition.X + myWidth - 1, myPosition.Y + myHeight) )
            myPosition.Y += 1;
        while ( Collision(otObjectList.wallIndex, myPosition.X + 1, myPosition.Y, myPosition.X + myWidth - 1, myPosition.Y + myHeight))
            myPosition.Y -= 1;
        myVelocity.Y = 0;
        myCurrentState = PlayerState.Ground;
    }
    else
    {
            myPosition.Y += myVelocity.Y;
    }
break;
```

**Collision Script:** This runs through all solid objects until there is a collision and returns true if there is.

```
private bool Collision( List<ObjWall> otWalls, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
{
    myBoundingBox.X = (int)Math.Ceiling(x1);
    myBoundingBox.Y = (int)Math.Ceiling(y1);
    myBoundingBox.Width = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Abs( x2 - x1));
    myBoundingBox.Height = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Abs( y2 - y1));
    foreach (ObjWall wall in otWalls)
    {
        if ( Box.Intersects( wall.Box ) )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Variable Explanations:**

**myBoundingBox** - every normal object builds off this abstract class. So, every object has a bounding rectangle.

**Box** - is a trait that comes from the abstract object class, it just returns the bounding rectangle.

**myVelocity** - is the players velocity, this is a Vector2 because floats provide cleaner looking gravity.

**myDforce** - is a float that changes the yvelocity in a positive force. I believe I should make it a constant.

**ObjectList** - this is a class that runs all Normal Object logic and contains a list of all the possible objects that can be in a room.

**myPosition** - This is another protected variable provided by the abstract class that normal objects are driven from. This is a vector 2, so it works using Floats.

For any more explanation in the code please ask!
*In advance, thanks for your time and Help.*
Cay.

Comment: are your Y positions not integers at any point ? if so you may be having truncation issues..

Comment: No, They are floats - and are changed by .5 ( default value of myDforce ) every frame during the fall state - or jump state. So, how would I be able to make the numbers precise as possible( fix the truncation)?  Also does casting change the number? I assume it does if it's truncated. IE (cast)4.4f would be 4?

Comment: When you "one pixel in", is it an X or Y pixel? Also, what does `myPosition.X` and `myPosition.Y` represent on the player? (i.e. top left/bottom left/bottom right etc.)

Comment: One pixel in - for the falling state, which is one pixel in on the bottom of the rectangle along the y access. Myposition has been added to variable explanations.
Thank you, Cay.

Comment: the first step would be to add some prints/use a debugger to check that truncation is indeed the issue here. once you isolate the problematic area you can think of ways to fix it. (maybe change the design to work with ints as much as possible to avoid the problem completly).

Comment: Having looked a bit closer at the Collision method, I agree with the above comment. The float arithmetic, `Math.Ceiling` and casting to int all introduce areas where errors can creep in. int is better but if decimal values are absolutely needed then use `decimal` instead of `float`.

Comment: Much thanks guys, I'll look right into this and tell you how it goes. I just have one question, what's the difference in results with float rather than decimal. Floats weren't by choice though, it was chosen by Vector2, therefor i'm not sure I can actually change the data-type.

Comment: Hey! Just tried out some different methods for comparing data types and I read an article on here about the casting process. So floats casted we'll be rounded down, even if the decimal is above 5. I found that interesting, and I thought to myself, ceiling them would probably do the trick. Until I found a post about using the system to convert the data types. To my satisfaction, the system conversion methods worked pretty well. I'm not sure how accurate it is because I still haven't looked into Debugging, any how I believe the problem was solved. Thank's everyone for the fast and quick replies!

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd call to `Collision` currently only checks the current position and then moves the Player down regardless of whether that action would cause a collision.

I can see you should be dealing with this with your 3rd call to Collision and moving the player back up but to remove some complexity from your code (slightly), you could simply have the 2nd call to collision checking the position + 1 and not moving the player if true.

This removes the need for the 3rd call to `Collision`, matches the logic you're using for most of the falling with the first call to collision (i.e. moving by gravity but not if the move would collide with a wall) and reduces the places your error can occur.

Comment: Hello thudbutt, I understand where you're coming from- yes the third call does look unnecessary, but In other programming languages I've created a similar project too in the past required this safety feature. It makes sure the player stays out of the blocks it fall into period. What you said was similar to what I've used in the past , but I found myself being inside the floor. So like said before, It's just a safety feature.